# Insert one line in database for multiple records formats using Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

I'm searching for a way to insert three beans in database. This an example of my CSV file:

```
H;001;2013-10-30;20;R;2013-10;DESP;2;foobar
D;003;3030;3032;2013-10;G;400;00001233399911;something
D;003;3030;3033;2013-10;A;100;00001233399912;something else
D;003;3030;3034;2013-10;V;500;00001233399913;something new
T;1;503.45
```

It has one header, N lines of data (starting with 'D') and a tail in the end (starting with 'T').

I've used `org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.LineAggregator` class to group the line before it passes to the Processor class. My doubt is how can I insert one line in database using the header + data + tail information. How can I keep the header, data and tail information in the same record in a database.

I also used the `org.springframework.classify.Classifier` class to group each bean to their corresponding writer.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?115590-Multi-line-Multi-record-flat-file) official forum thread or spring-batch example called [Multiline Order](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/order/internal/OrderItemReader.java).
The point is

1. have a custom `ItemReader<YouBeanClass>` delegate to `ItemReader<FieldSet>` who is responsible to create the right `FieldSet` based upon record header (`H,D,T`)
2. have a `PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer` to create the right `FieldSet` (attached to `ItemReader<FieldSet>` at point 1)
3. In `ItemReader<YouBeanClass>` rewrite `ItemReader.read()` and build up a YourBeanClass from every `H(D+)T` records range

After that you have a fully constructed `YourBeanClass` object.